# Kindle Worlds Publishing Benefits, Statistics?

Tags: self-publishing, kindle

Lots of articles/opinions on Kindle worlds out there. Not that much on actual numbers and facts that I can find. What I want to know is, if I produce some great content, how will my book be promoted and how much benefit will I receive?

One assumed benefit to using Kindle Worlds would be in getting a boost early on and getting a few fans by piggybacking on another author's franchise.

Problem 1: I have no idea how Amazon promotes Kindle worlds. If you don't go looking for it specifically, it doesn't seem to be pushed. So if I write a Silo Saga book, it doesn't show up when readers of the original series log in to Amazon and search for Silo stuff, etc.

How many people know about Kindle Worlds? I subscribe to Kindle Unlimited, an all you can eat book club that includes quite a few titles. I would probably give any of the books from Worlds a shot if I read the original book and was hungry for more. But books from Worlds aren't included in KU.

Problem 2: No idea about the success rate of Kindle World's stories. I can guess based on the limited number of reviews for many of these stories, and from what I see there, it is making me reconsider.

I'm still interested in working on a branch-off novel for one of my favorite books through Worlds. It would be a shortcut to getting a story done because the author has already created the main world, as well as the rules of the story for me. Just a little hesitant b/c it doesn't look like Amazon is pushing Worlds very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon doesn't really do anything to aggressively promote Kindle Worlds. However, if you go to their [Kindle eBooks page](http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-eBooks/b?ie=UTF8&node=154606011), they do have a link to [Kindle Worlds](http://www.amazon.com/b?node=6118587011) in the Popular Features section near the top of the page in the left navigation menu. Of course, that doesn't show up anywhere in their site map, and you have to actually go looking for the Kindle eBooks page to even find the link for the Kindle Worlds offerings. However, I have heard from some writers in a couple of forums that if your title does get bought by someone, then there is a possibility that Amazon may send out your title as a recommendation e-mail to others who may have bought books set in the same Kindle World. Of course, that all assumes that your book is selling well enough to draw their attention.

From what I have seen in different writer's forums, nobody is getting rich off of Kindle Worlds. They are simply writing stories that they probably would have given away for free on fan fiction sites anyway. If you have an interest in telling a story, then do so, just don't go in with the expectation that Amazon will be doing anything extra to boost your chances of selling just because it's set in one of the Kindle Worlds.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Unfortunately that's my conclusion as well. My hope isn't to make money, but simply build my email list to help seed my original works that will be done next year.